# How can I center using percentages?

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

As an experiment, I've been trying to center a DIV in a BODY tag using percentages in CSS.  I think I had it figured out at one point, but thanks to the magic of TopStyle not having a history once you save, I lost it.

So, here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="shadow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, here is my CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    margin: 10%;
}

div#box
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 740px;
    min-width: 80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    border: #CCCCCC thin solid;
}
```

To answer your immediate questions:

**Why am I using absolute positioning on the box?**
So that the box will accept 80% as it's height even without content to stretch it.

**Why am I width, min-width and min-height like this?**
Since I want the box DIV to take up 80% of the available space, it made sense to use minimums. I'm using a pixel width to make sure that no matter how small the area gets, it won't go any thinner than 740px, causing the browser to activate the horizontal scroll bar.  In theory, they content height should activate the vertical scroll bar if the content pushes passed 80% of the available area.

Now the trick is to get it dead centered and maintain a 10% space around the box.  I've tried applying "margin: 10%;" to BODY, then "padding: 10%;" to BODY, and finally "margin: 10%" to the box DIV.  All of those choices gives me the same result: it's centered horizontally but is acting strange vertically.  I'm not getting even space on all sides.  The only thing that is behaving as wanted is that the box DIV does appear to be using 80% of the available space.

It seems like this should be right.  The box DIV is taking up 80%, the margins are taking up 10% on each side (20% vertically and 20% horizontally), making 100%.  Not sure why it's not working.

I swear I had this working in a similar manner, and now I've lost it.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why the percentages don't seem to be displaying correctly and what solution I would need?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the end result supposed to be?

Comment: The vertical margins are taking 10% of the body's width! So for wide screens, you will have a HUGE top margin (it will look like 20+%).

Comment: thirtydot, what I want to see is a light gray background with a white box dead center with even spacing on all sides.  No matter how much the viewable area stretches, it should have space on all sides.  The only time this works for this example in FF is when the viewable area is or is almost perfectly square.

Comment: Jaroslav Jandek, sweet!  So that explains why the sides aren't even.  It's basing the vertical percentages off of the horizontal space.  Interesting.  So, now what do I do?

Comment: try the code in my answer, it should work in any resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body { background-color: #EEEEEE; }

div#box
{
    position: absolute;
    border: #CCCCCC thin solid;

    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;

    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;

    min-width: 740px;
    min-height: 500px;    
}
```

IE will allow for the DIV to shrink below your limits since min-width and min-height do not work.

Comment: shoots and scores!  Nicely done!  That is exactly the result I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: There is one issue though.  The reason I ad the percentage set on the min-height is that I wanted it to take up 80% space if it's empty.  However, if the content pushes down passed it, I want to box to expand to fit the content.  Right now, the content will push passed the border of the containing DIV.  Thoughts?

Comment: NOTE:  I went ahead and reversed the min-height and min-width with height and width, and it solved my problem with Chrome and FF, but not in IE as you pointed out.  Still, I call it a victory. :)

Comment: @linnium: overflowing can still happen since you are specifying both `height` and `min-height`. To allow the DIV to wrap around the text, you will have to remove the `height` (which would look ugly in IE) so there is a hack to do it using `height: 500px !ie;` (it's invalid CSS, though, but works well in FF and is not that bad in IE).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute;` from `#box`

Add this to `#box` - `margin:0 auto;`

Get rid of the stuff in `body`

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/AmYqn/4/show)

#### [JSFiddle Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/AmYqn/4/)

Comment: Myles,

When I try your solution, the box DIV centers horizontally and shrinks to 0px in height because I removed "position: absolute;".

Comment: I looked at the link you provided, and I'm seeing exactly what I see using my solution.  I have a 16:9 ratio monitor, and when I set the FF browser to full size, the box is getting pushed down and almost touching the bottom of the viewable area.  According to Jaroslav Jandek, this is because the top and bottom margins are being based off of the horizontal space instead of how I was expecting it: the vertical space.  Now I just gotta figure out how to "trick" it to doing what seems logical in code.